# Sacar una consulta en jtable

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, jtable

**No se porque pero necesito mostrar los datos que me saca esa consulta,
que por consola me funciona en una pantalla con JTable**

```
//TABLA
        JTabbedPane tabla = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        contentPane.add(tabla, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

        //Cambiar a consulta con un parametro
        ResultSet rs = Consulta.ejecutarSentencia("select * from jugadores", "nombre");
        modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[] {"Nombres","Apellidos"});

        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[] {rs.getString("nombre"),rs.getString("Apellidos")});
            }
            tabla.setModel((SingleSelectionModel) modelo);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás revolviendo al componente que muestra pestañas JTabbedPane con el componente que muestra la tabla JTabla.

Prueba de esta forma:

```
JTabbedPane componenteConPesañas = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
contentPane.add(componenteConPestañas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable tabla = new JTable();
tabla.setModel((SingleSelectionModel) modelo);
componenteConPestañas.addTab("Tabla", tabla); //aquí agregas la tabla al componente

    //Cambiar a consulta con un parametro
    ResultSet rs = Consulta.ejecutarSentencia("select * from jugadores", "nombre");
    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[] {"Nombres","Apellidos"});

    try {
        while(rs.next()) {
        modelo.addRow(new Object[] {rs.getString("nombre"),rs.getString("Apellidos")});
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```